# Firebase Notification when application is close (Issue)

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-push-notification

everybody, I m using firebase to receive a push notification from the server. Everything working fine when the application is running. I got the notification, I handle it and show it over notification tray. Seems perfect. Here is my code.

```
public class FirebasePushService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
    private static final String TAG = "FireBase main service ";

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Got Message: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());
        try {
            if (remoteMessage != null && remoteMessage.getNotification() != null
                    && remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody() != null) {
                String body = remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody();

                Log.d(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());
                Log.d(TAG, "Notification Message Body: " + body );

            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }}
```

Manifest code.

```
 <service android:name="app.asparagus.com.asparagus.firebase.FirebasePushService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
```

. The issue is when the application is closed. No log works of this class, nothing. But here is the interesting part. I can see the whole JSON from the server, and it is shown on notification tray ( whole JSON object is displayed). Really not getting what's wrong in my code. Check the image. 
1- The success case.
[image]

2- Unknown issue case[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for late reply I have found the solution and In case anyone else have issue with it.Here is from firebase documentation.
**Message types**

With FCM, you can send **two types** of messages to clients:

**Notification messages**, sometimes thought of as "**display messages.**"
`Data messages`, which are handled by the client app.
**Notification messages** contain a predefined set of user-visible keys. **Data messages**, by contrast, contain only custom key-value pairs. **Notification messages** can contain an optional data payload that is delivered when users tap on the notification.

**Use scenario**
**Notification message**    FCM automatically displays the message to end-user devices on behalf of the client app. Notification messages have a predefined set of user-visible keys and an optional data payload of custom key-value pairs.

**How to Send**
In a trusted environment such as Cloud Functions or your app server, use the Admin SDK or the HTTP and XMPP APIs: Set the notification key. May have optional data payload. Always collapsible.
**Use the Notifications composer**: Enter the Message Text, Title, etc., and send. Add optional data payload by providing Custom data. Always collapsible.

**Use scenario**

**Data message**    Client app is responsible for processing data messages. Data messages have only custom key-value pairs.
    In a trusted environment such as Cloud Functions or your app server, use the Admin SDK or the HTTP and XMPP APIs: Set the data key only. Can be either collapsible or non-collapsible.

[Link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#notifications_and_data_messages)

Answer (score 0):

From this [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive#backgrounded), I think the message should contain both notification and data payload.

Or maybe you can set the priority of the message to high like this [one](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#setting-the-priority-of-a-message)

```
{
  "to" : "bk3RNwTe3H0:CI2k_HHwgIpoDKCIZvvDMExUdFQ3P1...",
  "priority" : "high",
  "notification" : {
    "body" : "This week's edition is now available.",
    "title" : "NewsMagazine.com",
    "icon" : "new"
  },
  "data" : {
    "volume" : "3.21.15",
    "contents" : "http://www.news-magazine.com/world-week/21659772"
  }
}
```